# Microsoft cloud, how to authenticate the API

Tags: azure

Microsoft cloud, how to call API authentication, some authentication information is created there

```
import os
from azure.common.credentials import ServicePrincipalCredentials
from azure.mgmt.network import NetworkManagementClient


subscription_id = os.environ.get(
   'AZURE_SUBSCRIPTION_ID',
   '11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111') # your Azure Subscription Id
credentials = ServicePrincipalCredentials(
   client_id=os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_ID'],
   secret=os.environ['AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET'],
   tenant=os.environ['AZURE_TENANT_ID']
)

network_client = NetworkManagementClient(credentials, subscription_id)
```

AZURE_CLIENT_ID，AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET，AZURE_TENANT_ID，AZURE_ CLIENT_ ID，AZURE_ CLIENT_ SECRET，AZURE_ TENANT_ Where was the ID created?

Comment: The ID is based on Azure AD, you need to first create an azure ad app on azure, then https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-identity/azure.identity.clientsecretcredential?view=azure-python

Comment: I don't know where to create it. Can I create it in the azure web console

Comment: web console? Maybe you mean Azure CLI? You can create it on azure portal:  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ei2oo.png

Comment: azure.core.exceptions.HttpResponseError: (AuthorizationFailed) The client '357de489-830d-41a2-bc67-58566625b4e0' with object id '357de489-830d-41a2-bc67-58566625b4e0' does not have authorization to perform action 'Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/read' over scope '/subscriptions/49164d78-6722-4997-ae4e-3c9d5e0a2c6c/resourceGroups/HATest/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/hatest0155' or the scope is invalid. If access was recently granted, please refresh your credentials.     Now the error reporting permission is not enough. This permission is added on the web side